# Undefined method html_safe for Nokogiri Html Document

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, html-safe

I am trying to use .html_safe in the below description where I receive the error as Undefined method for Nokogiri HTML document.

**blogs_controller.rb**

```
@blog = Blog.find(19)
@description = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(@blog.description)
@description.search('a.fr-file').each do |desc|
  desc['href']= File.join(ActionController::Base.asset_host, desc['href'])
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<p><%= @description.html_safe %></p>
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html_safe` is a Rails method defined on `String` but not on `Nokogiri::HTML`.

I would try to translate the Nokogiri document into a HTML first:

```
<p><%= @description.to_html.html_safe %></p>
```